# Use Uppy with TypeScript and Vue2. Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, uppy

I've been trying to get Uppy working in my Vue TypeScript project for a few hours now. I am using Vue2 with the class components and Nuxt.

I have already tried to provide Uppy via a getter (since the [documentation](https://uppy.io/docs/vue/#Initializing-Uppy) says so),

```js
get uppy() {
    return Uppy<Uppy.StrictTypes>({
      restrictions: {
        allowedFileTypes: ["image/*"],
        maxNumberOfFiles: 1
      }
    }).use(ImageEditor, {
      id: "ImageEditor",
      quality: 0.8,
      cropperOptions: {
        viewMode: 1,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        background: false,
        autoCropArea: 1,
        responsive: true
      },
      actions: {
        revert: true,
        rotate: true,
        flip: true,
        zoomIn: true,
        zoomOut: true,
        cropSquare: true,
        cropWidescreen: true,
        cropWidescreenVertical: true
      }
    });
```

as well as an attribute.

```js
  private uppy =  Uppy<Uppy.StrictTypes>({
      restrictions: {
        allowedFileTypes: ["image/*"],
        maxNumberOfFiles: 1
      }
    }).use(ImageEditor, {
      id: "ImageEditor",
      quality: 0.8,
      cropperOptions: {
        viewMode: 1,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        background: false,
        autoCropArea: 1,
        responsive: true
      },
      actions: {
        revert: true,
        rotate: true,
        flip: true,
        zoomIn: true,
        zoomOut: true,
        cropSquare: true,
        cropWidescreen: true,
        cropWidescreenVertical: true
      }
    });
```

My entire file looks like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <dashboard
      :uppy="uppy"
      :plugins="['ImageEditor']"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Uppy from "@uppy/core";
import "@uppy/core/dist/style.css";
import "@uppy/dashboard/dist/style.css";
import "@uppy/image-editor/dist/style.css";
import { Dashboard } from "@uppy/vue";
import ImageEditor from "@uppy/image-editor";
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
  components: {
    Dashboard
  }
})
export default class uppyUpload extends Vue {
  private uppy =  Uppy<Uppy.StrictTypes>({
      restrictions: {
        allowedFileTypes: ["image/*"],
        maxNumberOfFiles: 1
      }
    }).use(ImageEditor, {
      id: "ImageEditor",
      quality: 0.8,
      cropperOptions: {
        viewMode: 1,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        background: false,
        autoCropArea: 1,
        responsive: true
      },
      actions: {
        revert: true,
        rotate: true,
        flip: true,
        zoomIn: true,
        zoomOut: true,
        cropSquare: true,
        cropWidescreen: true,
        cropWidescreenVertical: true
      }
    });

  beforeDestroy(): void {
    this.uppy.close();
  }
}
</script>
```

Already after compiling I get an warning in the console:
`WARN  in ./node_modules/@uppy/vue/lib/dashboard.js  "export 'h' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'`

However, when I try to load the page, I get the error that export is a unexpected token
[image: Unexpected token 'export']

Unfortunately, I have no more idea what I could do wrong. Do any of you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Hi have you found a solution for this? I'm also facing the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately not. We decided to program our own component, because we had some difficulties with Uppy in other places. And unfortunately there doesn't really seem to be an alternative.

We will also make our component open source. However, there is no timetable for this yet.